# Rspec & ShouldaMatchers with class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm getting following error:

```
1) Admin should belong to hospital
 Failure/Error: it {should belong_to(:hospital).with_foreign_key('medical_facility_id')  }
   Expected Admin to have a belongs_to association called hospital ()
```

with:

```
#admin_spec.rb
  it {should belong_to(:hospital).with_foreign_key('medical_facility_id')  }
```

Models are:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hospital
end

class Hospital < MedicalFacility
end
```

In `schema.rb`:

```
create_table "admins", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id",             null: false
    t.string   "role",                null: false
    t.integer  "medical_facility_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
end
```

How to correctly write test for this model? Maybe I should add
`class_name:"MedicalFacility" to the Admin model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell Rails about your exotic foreign key:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :hospital, foreign_key 'medical_facility_id'
end
```